# OpenCV coin detection and automated results checking

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

I am working on a project of coin identification.
First thing I with that I am stuck is correct coin extraction from the image, even from very simple image.
There are exists alot of good working methods for coin detection but all of them as I see need manual check after applying. I have tested two of them:

cv2.HoughCircles and threshold with findig countours after it .

Here some successfull examples of processing:

**cv2.HoughCircles, good result**

[image]

**cv2.HoughCircles, bad result**

[image]

But for the second image works great solution of threshloding and finding countours after it:

something like this:

```
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15, 15), 0)

#gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 1)
    (_,gray) = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
    print ellipse,type(ellipse)
    cv2.ellipse(color_img, ellipse, (0,255,0), 2)
```

produces very good result:

[image]

But for some other image it works very pure,

[image]

this has happened because coins are to close one from the other and bluring has merged them. It is very simple cas and for it i can just check if result is only one contour decline it . But sometimes it's more complicated. I want to implement some algo that tryes diferent metods of segmentation and chooses the best one. But its hard to encode for me this metric - has anybody Ideas how to do it ?

Original images from example:
this 3 are rather qute , but actually is not the rule - some of them has background some of them even not coins - thats why I am thinking about some postchecking process.

[image: enter coin1]

[image: enter coin2]

[image: enter coin3]

[image: enter coin4]

[image]

Comment: do you mean something like  ( without otsu and some decreased max thresh value ) 

cv2.threshold(gray,0,250,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

Comment: cv2.threshold(gray,160, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

works for this case but only for this one

Comment: is there always exactly one coint (2 sides) on the image? If you are able to use that information to find exactly 2 (nearly same sized) contours, the task should be very easy to solve.

Comment: would it help to divide the images in 2 partitioning sub images? before circle/ellipse detection?

Comment: > is there always exactly one coint (2 sides) on the image - actually not , but i can find out this information from height / width of my object with a huge probability.

Comment: > would it help to divide the images in 2 partitioning sub images? before circle/ellipse detection.   it was my first approach - to divide the image on two equal parts bot it does not work. some times coins are not good placed and this dividing broke coin layout

Comment: @OlegGolovanov on a side note, these coins seems interesting looking? what are these coins?

Comment: @Samer: It is an old roman coins.

Comment: @Micka: I think you are right first step must be a more or less realiable splitting. But how to do it

Answer (score 2):

I had success using a blob detector with the following parameters:

```
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector;
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
params.minThreshold = 150;
params.maxThreshold = 230;
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 50;
params.maxArea = 50000;
params.filterByConvexity = true;
params.minConvexity = 0.9;
params.maxConvexity = 1.0;

params.filterByCircularity = false;
params.filterByInertia = false;
params.filterByColor = false;
detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
```

And then find the blobs and draw the circles:

```
Mat SearchImage; // set to whatever picture contains coins
Mat DrawImage; // image to draw on with drawKeypoints
SearchImage.copyTo(DrawImage);
vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector->detect(SearchImage, keypoints);
drawKeypoints(SearchImage, keypoints, DrawImage, Scalar(0, 0, 0), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

EDIT:
This example code is in C++. For the Python interface see [here](http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) for examples.

Comment: Thanks for BlobDetector I like this approach . But the problem is anyway exists . In some cases it works in some not. I must fine tune threshold params for correct answer. And actually - brutferoce on minThreshold is not a bad idea but its not clear how to check results of algo - what is good answer and what is bad. No keypoints is bad . But one keypoint may be also bad answer (like in 3rd example )but may be not .