# Drawing a circle around a coin using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am trying to measure areas and perimeters of objects in snapshots and the most conservative way to do it seemed to be to use a reference object. One that is easily available to everyone is a coin as shown in this image. [image: coin] I have tried to use Hough Circles and contours in OpenCV but I can't seem to get a circle around the coin. I wonder if there is something basic I am missing. Below are the images, and the code for both methods. In case it matters in analyzing the problem, the original image's quality had to be lowered for me to be able to upload it here. Thanks!

```
# Function definitions
def show_image(window_name, image):
    cv.namedWindow(window_name)
    cv.imshow(window_name, image)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

def scale_to(image, fraction_of_original_size):
    width = int(image.shape[1] * fraction_of_original_size)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * fraction_of_original_size)
    dim = (width, height)
    resized = cv.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
    return resized

def edged_image(image):
    gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    gray = cv.dilate(gray, None, iterations=1)
    gray = cv.erode(gray, None, iterations=1)
    edges = cv.Canny(image=gray, threshold1=100, threshold2=200) 
    return edges

# Hough Circles method. Here we try to draw Hough circles.
scaled_image = scale_to(images[0], 0.25)
edged = edged_image(scaled_image)
circles = cv.HoughCircles(edged, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 10, 40,
                           param1=120,
                           param2=60,
                           minRadius=0,
                           maxRadius=0)
circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
for (x, y, r) in circles:
    cv.circle(scaled_image, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)
show_image("test", scaled_image)

# Contours method. Here we draw contours, fit with an ellipse and choose the ellipse with near-zero eccentricity.

scaled_image = scale_to(images[0], 0.25)
edged = edged_image(scaled_image)
contours_all, ret = cv.findContours(edged, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# drawn_image = cv.drawContours(scaled_image, contours_all, -1, (0, 0, 255), 4)
for cntr in contours_all:
    if len(cntr) > 4:
        ellipse = cv.fitEllipse(cntr)
        (center,axes,orientation) = ellipse
        majoraxis_length = max(axes)
        minoraxis_length = min(axes)
        eccentricity=(np.sqrt(1-(minoraxis_length/majoraxis_length)**2))
        if eccentricity < 0.08:
            cv.ellipse(scaled_image,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
        print(eccentricity)
show_image("test", scaled_image)
```

But the Hough Circles method produced this image with lots of circles but none around the coin. [image: this]
The contour method produces this image, with a tiny dot. [image: contourresult]

Comment: one mistake is applying Canny. HoughCircles does that already, so effectively you've got *two* applications of Canny.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV coin detection and automated results checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270477/opencv-coin-detection-and-automated-results-checking)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV. Note that all the parameters need to be tuned carefully for this image. Also note that the rim of the coin is not detected as it is too close in brightness to the skin and the circle between the rim and center of the coin is stronger.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Apply Gaussian Blur
- Get Canny edges
- Get Hough Circles
- Draw circle on input
- Save result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('coin.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Gaussian filter
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, ksize=(7,7), sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)

# get canny edges
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 20, 200)

# get Hough circles
min_dist = int(ww/20)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=200, param2=50, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
print(circles)

# draw circles
result = img.copy()
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    r = int(r)
    cv2.circle(result, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('coin_canny.jpg', canny)
cv2.imwrite('coin_circle2.jpg', result)

# show images
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Canny edge image:

[image]

Resulting Circle:

[image]

X,Y,Radius = [[[396.5 390.5  80.2]]]

ADDITION:

Here is the code for the reduces size image. I used cv2.resize() since I do not know scale_to(). I had to change the Canny arguments and then the HoughCircle arguments.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('coin.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# resize image to 1/4
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(0,0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Gaussian filter
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, ksize=(3,3), sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)

# get canny edges
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 20, 140)

# get Hough circles
min_dist = int(ww/20)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=200, param2=40, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
print(circles)

# draw circles
result = img.copy()
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    r = int(r)
    cv2.circle(result, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('coin_canny.jpg', canny)
cv2.imwrite('coin_circle2.jpg', result)

# show images
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

ADDITION2:

Removing the canny step and adding increased contrast, does slightly better.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('coin.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Gaussian filter
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, ksize=(7,7), sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)

# increase contrast
contrast = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(gray, in_range=(100,200), out_range=(0,255)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# get Hough circles
min_dist = int(ww/20)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(contrast, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=400, param2=50, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
print(circles)

# draw circles
result = img.copy()
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    r = int(r)
    cv2.circle(result, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('coin_contrast5.jpg', contrast)
cv2.imwrite('coin_circle5.jpg', result)

# show images
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('contrast', contrast)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Increased contrast image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Another way that seems to work well is to use morphology open to darken the inside of the watch circle with a 15x15 size elliptical kernel.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ran your code verbatim, except for the rescaling factor, but got a circle that is inside the coin and center not coincident with the coin's center. I would like to post the image but can't seem to be able to attach it to the comment. In contrast, your circle is almost perfect. What might I be missing? Apologies if it is too basic a question.

Comment: What rescaling factor?  If you change my code, you may have to change some of the arguments to either or both Canny or HoughCircles. As I mentioned, I had to manually tune the arguments with trial and error to find the ones that gave the best fit circle. Most of my attempts produce either too many circles, or no circles, or smaller offset circles as you seem to have produced. If you have enough points, you can edit your original post. To put an image in a comment, you will have to upload it to some free image hosting  site and put the URL in the comment. Images cannot be posted inside comments

Comment: Thank you. The only part of your code I changed was this:

img = cv2.imread('coin.jpg')

to:

scaled_image = scale_to(image_read_from_file, 0.25)
img = scaled_image

The scale_to function is in my original posting. It just scales the image to a lower resolution.

Comment: Found a free site to upload the image for a day: here it is: thanks again. https://i.postimg.cc/QtTd7VVh/Not-APerfect-Circle.png

Comment: What is "scale_to"?  What tool provides that? I do not understand your change.

Comment: See the ADDITION in my answer. I used cv2.resize() in place of scale_to().

Comment: OK, I see. You created a function called scale_to that actually uses cv2.resize() in you original code. The difference in my code for the resized image is that I used the default interpolation of bilinear and you use inter_area.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. See my comments above yours.

Comment: To conclude, I will also add other means of detection, like color ranges to narrow down the possibilities for the houghCircle method. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I had tried thresholding and morphology on the grayscale image and got results similar to my posted solution. If you can get a clean circle by color range thresholding, that might work slightly better.

Comment: HoughCircles already does a Canny. why is everyone applying an additional canny to the input? that's superfluous and can actually hurt the algorithm because now you're duplicating every ridge. besides, "hough circles on a coin" is a frequent enough question that this warrants flagging as a duplicate and perhaps adding decent answers to previous questions.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz. I used it, because without it, I could not get an equivalently good result. I tried thresholding w/morphology as well as median filtering. None produced a better result. Any suggestions how to improve applying it without an extra Canny?

Comment: @fmw42 your suggestions are very helpful. Christoph, I already looked over the other questions on Hough circles and coins and spent half a day experimenting before posting my question. They are about coins on a clean background. Here, it is about detecting one known coin to be used as a length reference, so I don't believe it duplicates other questions.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - I followed your suggestion of avoiding the Canny edge detector and it worked uncannily perfectly on all the images! Thank you very much for the suggestion. Also, the other questions on coins and Hough circles talk about multiple coins on "clean" surfaces. This solution worked poorly on a collection of coins on a carpet which has a lot of "curls." But this is not my problem, so it does not affect me.

Comment: @user4562262 Post your new solution with the same image.

Comment: @fmw42 The new solution is exactly the same as yours, except that we don't use the result  of the Canny operation. Instead, we use the image on the line prior to it. This is the line where we use the variable gray for the image:     circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=200, param2=50, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

Comment: @fmw42 You can try creating a trackbar for the various parameters within `ccv2.HoughCircles`, that way it will be a lot easier I think. +1

Comment: Yes, trackballs would have helped zone in on the optimal parameters. I was just lazy and adjusted them manually.

Comment: @user4562262. I get a circle closer to the size of the coin using the extra Canny operation than I do without it.

Comment: I have added a second ADDITION in my answer that replaced the canny step with increased contrast on the grayscale image. This seems to work even better.